# Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$, then $\partial A$ is closed.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$, then $\partial A$ is closed.

To show this I need to show that $$(\partial A)^c = X \setminus \partial A = (A \setminus \partial A) \cup (A^c \setminus \partial A)$$ is open.

Now I need to look at the cases $x \in A \setminus \partial A$ and $x \in A^c \setminus \partial A $ and see if I can find open sets of $x$ in both cases that are contained in the sets $x$ lies in.

First if $x \in A \setminus \partial A $, then $x \notin \partial A \implies \exists U_x \in \tau$ s.t $U_x \cap A^c = \emptyset \implies U_x \subset A$ and thus $x \in A \setminus \partial A  $ would be open.

Now what bothers me with this is that I have no information about the openess of closedness of $A$, then how can I even know that there is an open set $U_x$ if $A$ is not given to be open? Do I have to assume that $A$ is an open subset of $X$?

The second case is pretty much same except that there I would have that $U_x \cap A = \emptyset$ instead of $A^c$.

Comment: Can you recall the definition of the boundary?

Comment: $\partial A = \overline{A} \setminus int(A)$?

Comment: Do you mean $A^c \setminus int (A)$, where $A^c$ is the closure and $int (A)$ the interior?

Comment: Yes I do indeed!

Comment: I am a bit confused then. From $(\partial A)^c = X \setminus \partial A $ you seem to assume that $(\cdot)^c$ stands for the complement.

Comment: Yes it seems that there is confusion here. I denote the closure with overline and by $(\cdot)^c$ I denote the complement.

Comment: Okay.... anyway, try to show (1) closure is a closed set , (2) $ int (A)$ is open, and (3) $\partial A = \overline A \cap (X\setminus (int(A)))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\partial A := \overline{A} \setminus \text{int}(A)$, and so $(\partial A)^c = (X \setminus \overline{A}) \cup \text{int}(A)$, which is the union of two open sets and therefore is open.

Answer (score 1):

The closure of $A$ is the set smallest set $\overline{A}$ that is closed and contains $A$. The interior is given by the largest subset of $A$ that is open. The boundary $\partial A$ of $A$ is their difference. This means that $A - \partial A$ is the interior which is open by definition. Notice that $A^c - \partial A$ is the complement of the closure of $A$. Because the closure is closed by definition, $A^c - \partial A$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

The boundary is $K \setminus U$, where $K$ is the closure of $A$ and therefore is closed, and $U$ is the interior of $A$ and therefore is open.  Therefore, the boundary also is $K \cap (X \setminus U)$.  Since $U$ is open, $X \setminus U$ is closed, so the boundary is the intersection of two closed sets ($K$ and $X \setminus U$) and hence is itself closed.